# Reordering a matrix of ordinal scores according to individual development

Tags: ordinal-data

I have the following situation: 12 ordinal factors have been measured on 200 individuals of different ages (some are young children, some others are young adults). These 12 factors have the ordered levels 0 < 1 < 2 < 3; and those levels correspond to developmental scores observed on the individuals during their growth (e.g., levels of dental or skeletal development, etc.). "0" means that the trait is not developed at all, and the terminal stage "3" means that the trait is fully developed (the individual is "adult" as regards this trait).

The question is the following: is there a way / an algorithm to reorder the columns of the $200 \times 12$ matrix according to the speed of maturation of the traits? I.e., the leftmost column will be the trait that reaches most often its terminal stage very early during the individual growth, and the rightmost column will be the one that reaches most often its terminal stage later than any other factor. (To be exhaustive, the full speed of "transitions" among all four stages should ideally be taken into account: the traits that mature faster must be on the right, and the traits that mature slower must be on the left.)

Is there any ordination technique for such a problem? (And I guess that the rows must also be sorted during those calculations, thus delivering a kind of "2d-sorting" of the matrix, with "most adult" individuals at the bottom, and "less developed" individuals at the top...)

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that the problem description is incomplete. If one patient has measures`1 2 2 2 2 3` and the other one has measures `1 1 1 1 3 3`, which one has more developed traits? The first one, because all those 2s are higher then all the 1s? Or the second one, because she has two 3s and the other one only 2? You will need a clear winning rule.

Comment: True, this is a good point, and a true problem (with only arbitrary solutions). Two questions: 1/ This only matters for reordering patients, not for reordering traits. So, I guess that (expectedly) we also need to define a rule to reorder patients even if the final goal is to reorder traits? 2/ Does a rule-of-thumb such as "sum of trait values" to reorder patients seem admissible? (And in case of ties, go for the greatest number of "3"s, although this is perfectly arbitrary once again...)
(Hope that everything is clear.)

Comment: As for the traits I imagine a linear regression with the trait and the age as predictors and the development score of that trait as dependent variable. You could then order the traits by their coefficients in that regression: traits with a high coefficient need less additional time to develop a high score. And I mean "linear regression" in the broadest sense, e. g. ordered logistic regression as in https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/r/c6s5

Comment: As for ordering the patients there may be a not arbitrary solution in Item Response Theory (IRT). Assume each trait was an item in a questionnaire and each questionnaire has 4 possible ordered answers a patient could tick. Which score of which trait has what influence on the overall development of the syndrome.  That is pretty much what IRT tries to answer. If it works or not depends on whether these traits do measure a common factor.